# Import-Module works only when piped from Get-Module

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, import-module

I wrote a simple PowerShell module. I need to keep more versions of the module. <del>All paths to versions are added to `$env:PSModulePath`.</del> I'm facing strange problem when importing the module to my session.

This fails:

```
Import-Module Contoso.PowerShell -RequiredVersion "0.0.2"
```

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'Contoso.PowerShell' with version '0.0.2'
was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module Contoso.PowerShell -RequiredVersion "0.0.2"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Contoso.PowerShell:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleWithVersionNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

And now the strange thing - the module with the "0.0.2" version exists. I can successfully list it (with `Get-Module -ListAvailable`). I can even import it and work with it, but the only way how to do it is this:

```
Get-Module Contoso.PowerShell -ListAvailable |
    ? { $_.Version -eq "0.0.2" } |
    Import-Module
```

Everything works like a charm then. The question is: **WHY?** I'd like to be able to import the module with the first simple command.

**EDIT:**

Here is how I store the versions of the module:

```
 Get-Module Contoso.PowerShell -ListAvailable
```

```
    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Contoso.PowerShell\Contoso.PowerShell.0.0.1


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     0.0.1      Contoso.PowerShell


    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Contoso.PowerShell\Contoso.PowerShell.0.0.2


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     0.0.2      Contoso.PowerShell
```

And sorry for confusion - I do NOT have paths to each version in the PSModulePath environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `Import-Module` works is because it uses a different parameter set; one where it accepts one or more `[PSModuleInfo]` objects, which are what `Get-Module` returns.

Likely, it uses the work already done by `Get-Module` to determine which file to load.

The next question then is "why doesn't `Import-Module` find the version the same way `Get-Module` does?" and the answer to that is "I don't know."

<s>While they should be consistent in any case, a possible cause for trouble is your directly structure. How are you storing multiple versions?</s>

It looks to me like your module paths are incorrect.

Your structure should be:

```
Contoso.PowerShell\0.0.2
Contoso.PowerShell\0.0.3
```

etc.

The module files go directly in the version number folder, and it shouldn't additionally have the name inside it.

You can see this structure by using `Install-Module` to install one from a repository and taking a look at how it handles it.

Comment: I edited my question - info about how I store module versions is added.

Comment: I changed the folder structure and now everything works. Thanks!